# groovy script from jenkins scriptler not working. classpath issue

Tags: mysql, jenkins, jdbc, groovy

Trying to connect to mysql db using groovy script in jenkins via scriptler plugin.
Using jdbc mysql connector for the same.

mysql connector jar file is present in classpath of machine where jenkins is running.
running only 1 machine for jenkins.

below is the code snippet:

```
import java.sql.*
import groovy.sql.Sql
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver())

try{
    def dbURL = 'jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/Employee_DB'
    def dbUserName = 'root'
    def dbPassword = 'root'
    def dbDriver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    def db = Sql.newInstance(dbURL,dbUserName,dbPassword,dbDriver)
    List authors = db.rows('SELECT name FROM Employee')
    print authors

}catch(Exception e){
    print "exception"
}finally{
    //db.close()
}
```

But getting exception saying:

```
Script1.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
@ line 5, column 30.
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver())
```

Same piece of code if run like

```
groovy 1.groovy
```

Execution is successful.

But jenkins scriptler is unable to detect this jar file.

in manager jenkins -> system information, i could see system environment variables set as well.

Need help.

Comment: You should never call `DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver())`, if the driver is on the classpath, and it is a JDBC 4+ driver, it will be loaded automatically. A JDBC driver registers itself with `DriverManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a bug from the Jenkins that it does not read the environment variables nor the Jenkins defined variables it takes into account the java native path and it is /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/ext

so add the Jdbc jar in the above path and restart the jenkins

hope this helps